# Dedupe while or after write

Tags: parsing, coding, speed

I have a summary tool written in python that reads input files, and writes them into a summary file. I have the following stipulations:

1. No duplicates.
2. If it exists, add a count to it.

Is it better / faster to write one GIANT output file THEN de-duplicate the entries or to dedupe as you go (ie, each write command checks before writing)?

The small files are about 100-300k each, there can be hundreds of thousands of these, and the final output file is usually 1-4 MB.

A sample line in the file would be like this:

`String,number`

I would be checking the string for dupes. If it were a dupe, I would output:

`string,COUNT,number(additive)`

as in, I would keep add the numbers every time I'd get a duplicate, and keep a count of how many times it was duplicated.

I would say there are mostly duplicates.

Comment: What's the key for the duplication? A string? How many duplicates are there (is almost everything a duplicate, is almost nothing a duplicate)?

Comment: Good point... I added info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but I'll take a stab at it. Writing to memory is almost always going to be faster than writing to disk. It would be better to use a data type like a `Set` in Java that doesn't have duplicate entries and keep track of them as you go. Then, once you have the data structure in memory, write it to disk.

Comment: Definitely if it the end output is 1-4MB, since that means lots of duplicates -> no need to fear that there's not enough memory -> no need to go to the file system for a merge sort.